# Simulate button press in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am currently working on a Chrome extension that automates various tasks. I have successfully implemented several features, but I am currently facing a challenge that has me stuck.

I am trying to automate the submission of a form by either clicking a send button or simulating the "enter" key press. Specifically, I want my code to automatically submit the content of a textbox. Despite trying various approaches, I haven't been able to find a solution that works.

I have explored different methods, including using click() on the button element and triggering a keyboard event to simulate the "enter" key press, but none seem to produce the desired result.

This a snippet of the current code, I have tried so many different ways and I can't find the problem/ solution

```js
     (textarea) {
        textarea.focus();

        textarea.innerHTML =
          "ey! Our team has been OBSESSING over your page and we’d love to collab! \nWe’ve done over $40M on Amazon and one of our best affiliates generated $100k in profit!\n\nWe have over 20,000 units in stock, and would love to build a long term relationship with you.\n\nRequest a sample from the listing and we’ll get it dispatched ASAP";

        textarea.focus();

        document.execCommand("insertText", false, "H");
        textarea.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", { bubbles: true }));

        setTimeout(function () {
          // Create a new keyboard event for the Enter key
          var enterKeyEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
            key: "Enter",
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            view: window,
          });

          // Dispatch the keyboard event on the document
          document.dispatchEvent(enterKeyEvent);
        }, 10000); // Adjust the initial delay as needed
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding some additional events :

```
textarea.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
textarea.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
textarea.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup', { bubbles: true }));
textarea.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));
textarea.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
```

and then click on submit button.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I am using the button.click() method after this code, yet, that does not resolve my issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).